# Preg_replace with optional newlines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm currently struggling with a regular expression. Some strings I process have newlines at the end, some don't. But I want those newlines to be outside the html I'm adding. At first I didn't have the newline-code in my regex, but then the newlines came back before the closing -tag. I fixed that with the current code, but now it doesn't process strings correct anymore which don't have a newline at the end.

So I'm trying to make a change to my code, to return the newline when it's there, but also process the string when there's no newline.

My current code:

```
preg_replace('/^(m:|maken:)(.*)([\r\n])/i', $makenblokje . '<em class="markeerroze">$2</em>$3', $regel, 1, $teller);
                               ^^^^^^^^                                                    ^^
```

I think the solution should be in the underlined parts, but I couldn't get it fixed with the result I'm looking for yet.

Comment: As a guess... What if you add a ? at the end (before the /i). This is a 0 or 1 match occurrences on the newline. So it becomes... /^(m:|maken:)(.*)([\r\n])?/i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a pattern optional (i.e., allow 0 or 1 instances of it) by following it with a `?`, so this should do it for you:

```
'/^(m:|maken:)(.*)([\r\n])?/i'
```

But I think it would be easier to just strip all newlines coming in, it's not like they'll render in the output anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`[\r\n]` matches `\r` or `\n`. In order to match any kind of linebreak, use `\R` and `?` to make it optional:

```
preg_replace('/^(m:|maken:)(.*)(\R?)/i', $makenblokje . '<em class="markeerroze">$2</em>$3', $regel, 1, $teller);
```